# Cloud Function Error: Forbidden unless I open function to allUsers

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

- This is a web page located on Firebase Hosting, served dynamically through a rewrite to a Cloud Function
- When browsing to the url, I receive "Error: Forbidden
  Your client does not have permission to get URL [/theURL] from this server.
- Everything works as long as I have "allUsers" added as a Cloud Functions Invoker on the function via the GCP console.  I have confirmed this with testing just throwing that one switch and getting two different results.
- I am logged into my Chrome browser with the same Google account as the owner of the GCP project
- I am logged in to my Firebase website (Firebase Authentication and Firestore roles management) using the same Google account, with a Firebase __session cookie and all.
- This started when I upgraded my Node.js engine from 8 to 10 with the recent warnings from Google that they're dropping support for 8.  (I am assuming, but have no real idea, that the version 8 runtime environment didn't have this feature?)
- I wrote these Cloud Functions without any knowledge of GCP authentication, so I am relatively confident that my coding inside the Cloud Function is secure, but if there is another layer of security that I could/should be using, I'm all for it.
- I will want this website to be publicly accessible, but I can granulate the functions to public vs. non-public if necessary.  (Basically, I was writing them as all publicly accessible and internally authenticated/secured anyway.)
- I'm not very knowledgeable at all about the GCP authentication requirements, so it's hard for me to pin this down to one central question, but here are some questions I know I don't know:

  - Should Firebase Hosting be added as a member to GCP's authentication groups, so that GCP only allows service of a Cloud Function to the rewrite requests?  It seems that would be the most secure and straightforward method.
  - Why is GCP telling my I'm forbidden when I'm the owner of the whole doggone project?  Does this have to do with Firebase Rewrite or maybe HTTP requests being anonymous?  If so, then how does one authenticate for a Cloud Function anyway?

Sorry for the large scope of the question; any guidance in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

GCP allUsers is not related to Firebase Authentication.  They deal with different sets of users.  A function should have GCP allUsers invoker permission in order to allow access from web and mobile apps where users are signed in with Firebase Auth.  GCP does not check the Firebase user - that is up to the function to do, if it wants, using the Firebase Admin SDK.

Comment: Thank you; that helps clarify what I thought about them being two separate processes.  Does it sound to you from my use case details that I should just have allUsers as members on my public-facing functions and leave it at that?

Comment: You will need it for each of the functions that you want to invoke from your app.  I don't know about each and every one of your functions, so you will have to judge for yourself.